# Hash with key as an array type

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go

How to create a key as array in Go for map.
For example in ruby I can implement it such:

```
quarters = {
  [1, 2, 3] => 'First quarter',
  [4, 5, 6] => 'Second quarter',
  [7, 8 ,9] => 'Third quarter',
  [10, 11, 12] => 'Fourh quarter',
}
quarters[[1, 2, 3]] 
# => "First quarter"
```

How the same will be looked in Golang ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Array types (unlike slices) in Go are comparable, so there is nothing magical in it: you can just define it like any other maps: [`map[KeyType]ValueType`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types) where `KeyType` will be `[3]int` and `ValueType` will be `string`.

> The [comparison operators](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) == and != must be fully defined for operands of the key type; thus the key type must not be a function, map, or slice.

```
m := map[[3]int]string{}

m[[3]int{1, 2, 3}] = "First quarter"
m[[3]int{4, 5, 6}] = "Second quarter"
m[[3]int{7, 8, 9}] = "Third quarter"
m[[3]int{10, 11, 12}] = "Fourth quarter"

fmt.Println(m)
```

Output:

```
map[[1 2 3]:First quarter [4 5 6]:Second quarter 
    [7 8 9]:Third quarter [10 11 12]:Fourth quarter]
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/xfMirCe_cq).

To query an element:

```
fmt.Println(m[[3]int{1, 2, 3}]) // Prints "First quarter"
```

You can also create the map in one step:

```
m := map[[3]int]string{
    [3]int{1, 2, 3}:    "First quarter",
    [3]int{4, 5, 6}:    "Second quarter",
    [3]int{7, 8, 9}:    "Third quarter",
    [3]int{10, 11, 12}: "Fourth quarter",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that `array` in ruby and `array` in go are different data structures. Go array is not mutable, while ruby `array` is. Go `slice` is a lot more similar data structure to ruby `array`. However, you cannot use `slices` as keys in go, as pointed out in icza's answer.

So to answer your question:

> How the same will be looked in Golang ?

It is impossible, you cannot have a dictionary that maps `dynamic arrays` to `strings` in go. However, you could convert `slices` to `arrays` and use them as keys, as very well explained by icza.